# Vue Options API not rendering template syntax

Tags: vuejs3

I have a vue 3 starter app that was bootstrapped with `npm init vue@latest`

I am trying to display a simple div on the page using Vue 3 options API. I have the following code in main.ts:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'

type Data = {
    title: String
}

const App = {
    template: "<div>{{title}}</div>",
    data(): Data {
        return {
            title: "My first vue component"
        }
    }
}
const app = createApp(App)

app.mount('#app')
```

And inside index.html, I have the div with an id of "app", but nothing is being rendered on the screen.

```
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>
  </body>
```

The issue is the same when using just the template:

```
const App = {
    template: "<div>Hello World</div>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding an alias for vue to vite.config.ts

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    vueJsx(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
      'vue': 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js'
    }
  }
})
```